# Como trocar o UUID de uma particao via código em C?

Tags: c, linux, terminal

Estou fazendo um programa em C, e pelo Linux, tenho conseguido "pegar" facilmente o UUID, com o comando `blkid`.

Esse programa precisa saber se o disco onde foi instalado ainda é o mesmo e permitir trocar o UUID por próprio.

É possível trocar programaticamente o UUID de uma partição? Não achei nada conclusivo pesquisando na internet.

Comment: Roberval, acredito que essa pergunta vai acabar sendo fechada devido ao escopo do site (assim como a falta de informações relevantes na pergunta). Dito isso, assumindo que você tenha uma partição `ext4` no Ubuntu  dê uma olhada [nessa resposta](http://askubuntu.com/a/132087/19854) do [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/), o comando `tune2fs /dev/{device} -U {uuid}` deve fazer o que você quer.

Comment: obrigado pela dica!  ainda estou aprendendo...   desculpe p mau jeitro!

Comment: acontece que estou fazendo um programa, em c, que deve ler o UUID do disco, para saber se ele ainda esta instalado no mesmo computador / disco..   isso esclarece? era essa explicacao que faltava?

Comment: Sugiro repensar seu programa, mexer no UUID do disco do usuário pode quebrar outras aplicações existentes. Pode até existir alguma razão legítima para isso, mas quase sempre não é. Se precisa identificar o disco do usuário, é mais elegante guardar o UUID existente e armazenar em algum lugar para comparação futura, sem mexer.

Comment: Da minha parte, apenas foi uma recomendação. Se eu tivesse a resposta de pronto, teria dado, pois acho que não cabe a nós avaliar como você vai usar o conhecimento ou não. Só achei importante avisar, pois é algo a ser considerado, caso você for mesmo optar por essa solução na sua aplicação.

Comment: Olá @Roberval, imagina, a questão aqui não é pessoal, todos nós tivemos que aprender o formato do site um dia. Como você está modificando a pergunta para esclarecer os pontos eu sugeriria que você inclui-se um exemplo de código e mais detalhes sobre seu ambiente: "Qual a sua distribuição? Quais sistemas de arquivos você está administrando? Por que você está fazendo isso?" Para mais informações de uma olhada em [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: entendo @Anthony Accioly, mas .. em outro post , coloquei um exemplo de prog em C++ e tags C e C++.. nossa.. Um rapaz la.. acabou comigo, sempre de maneira muito educada.... mas me senti muito mal, principalemtne porque nao sabia fazer a pergunta.  bom efins ele me negativou... bom.. agora eu tenho REAL medo de voces....  mas como tenho que aprender... vamos la..

Comment: eu ainda nao entendi... o porque isso nao eh uma questao de programacao...

Comment: a solucao atual que estou usando eh um **system("tune2fs /dev/sde5 -U f0acce91-a416-474c-8a8c-43f3ed3768f9");**   OU SEJA..estou programando em C.. porem tive que usar comandos do sistema...  pena... deu um trabalhao...  eh bem ruim ser novato.. e ser esnobado pelos veteranos...   vou continuar com as pesquizas.... talvez uma hora eu ache os comandos corretos em C pra trocar o UUID... e label de particoes.  eh o meu projeto atual, vou ter que fazer.